# Rails model scope returning undefined method in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I defined a named scope for my class:

```rb
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  include AASM

  scope :is_effective_at, ->(date) { where('? BETWEEN starts_at AND expires_at', date) }

end
```

In the rails console, when I try to access the scope:

```rb
irb(main):002:0> Contract.is_effective_at(Date.current)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):2
        1: from (irb):2:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `is_effective_at' for Contract (call 'Contract.connection' to establish a connection):Class)
```

When I reload the console with `reload!` it works, but all other scopes from other classes are working normal. 
I can't get it why this class is not loading any scopes, the only difference from this one to the other is that this class has 120 LOC.

Any ideias?

Comment: Are you sure `Contract` in the console is correcly resolved? Could you check `show-source Contract` in pry?